# How to test a contiguous/related changes using googletest/googlemock framework?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to test class Foo for return of it's method status, by using googletest/googlemock. To my understanding for every call of the method `counter()` the value of **m_counter** should be increasing by one, however I am always getting one or same result, i.e. **m_counter** never reaches the limit. Does it mean all data are cleared for every call? Can someone tell help me how to test a contiguous/related changes using google test? It looks Every call to `counter()` is it's own story (not related), even if the object is same?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()            { m_counter = 0;}
    void counter()   { m_counter++;  }
    int getCounter() { return  m_counter;}
    int status()     { return (m_counter>=5)?0:1;}
private:
    int m_counter; 
};

TEST_F(TestFoo, TestStatus_1)
{
    Foo fooP;
    fooP.counter();
    ASSERT_TRUE(fooP.status() == 0);
    std::cout<<fooP.getCounter()<<std::endl;  //should be 1
    fooP.counter();
    ASSERT_TRUE(fooP.status() == 0);
    std::cout<<fooP.getCounter()<<std::endl;  //should be 2
    fooP.counter();
    ASSERT_TRUE(fooP.status() == 0);
    std::cout<<fooP.getCounter()<<std::endl;  //should be 3
    fooP.counter();
    ASSERT_TRUE(fooP.status() == 0);
    std::cout<<fooP.getCounter()<<std::endl;  //should be 4
    fooP.counter();
    ASSERT_TRUE(fooP.status() == 0);
    std::cout<<fooP.getCounter()<<std::endl;  //should be 5
    fooP.counter();
    ASSERT_TRUE(fooP.status() == 1);
    std::cout<<fooP.getCounter()<<std::endl;  //should be 6

}
```

Comment: So what is the results you get? Are any of the ASSERTs triggering? What is the output on cout?

Answer (score -2):

Bug in code:

```
int status()     { return (m_counter>=5)?0:1;}
```

should be:

```
int status()     { return (m_counter<=5)?0:1;}
```

Comment: That was typo error thanks! However does not change the result.